# get a variables by GET in method get in DetailView django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, detailview

Im trying to get the variable "segundos" by GET in the Detail View, im trying to get it by the method get:

the js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var segundos=340;
    console.log(segundos);
    $.ajax({
        data : {'segundos':segundos},
        url : '/ajax/puzzle-1/',
        type : 'GET',    
    });
});
```

views.py

```
class PuzzleView(DetailView):
    model = Puzzle
    template_name = 'puzzle.html'

    def get (self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        seconds = request.GET["segundos"]
        self.object = self.get_object()
        ranking = Ranking.objects.create(puzzle_id=self.object.id,usuario=self.request.user,segundos=seconds,puesto=89)
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context) 

class RankingView(ListView):
    model = Ranking
    template_name = 'ranking.html'
    queryset = Ranking.objects.filter(puzzle_id=1).order_by('segundos')[:3]

class PuzzleAjaxView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'ranking.html'
```

But i get the famous error "MultiValueDictKeyError". If i try the same method "get" but with a TemplateView, i can get the variable, but not with DetailView

Just in case, my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('puzzle.views',
    url(r'^actividad/puzzle/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$',PuzzleView.as_view(),name='puzzle'),
    url(r'^ajax/puzzle-1/.*$', PuzzleAjaxView.as_view(),name='ajax'),
    url(r'^ranking/.*$', RankingView.as_view(),name='ranking'),

    )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 seconds = request.GET("segundos")
```

You can't just call the `GET` `MultiValueDict`.  You must access by dictionary lookup. It is a subclass of a `dict`.

```
request.GET.get('segundos')
request.GET['segundos']
```

## Update

For future reference, your exception traceback would have explained all of this, but the error message should be pretty clear: something along the lines of `segundos` not being a valid key in the `MultiValueDict`.

I assume your `PuzzleView` (what you are calling the `DetailView`) never gets passed any GET parameters because your example shows GET params only with your AJAX call, which is mapped to your `PuzzleAjaxView` (what you are calling the `TemplateView`

What is determining whether or not your `get` function works or not isn't based on the fact that your view class is a `TemplateView` or `DetailView`, it's the fact that `segundos` is only passed to your AJAX view.

In other words.. any view (`TemplateView, DetailView`, doesn't matter) accessing a `GET` dict via direct lookup `request.GET['foobar']` will fail if that get parameter isn't passed in.

Comment: You also want to do `request.GET.get('segundos', False)` so your application doesn't throw an exception when the user calls it without setting that GET variable. Also, I'd recommend naming your variables in English.

Comment: @dan-klasson one of the purposes of `get` is to ensure it doesn't throw exceptions. The default value in the absence of the second argument is `None`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita Sorry, i have my code with ['segundos'], when i pasted my code i made a little modification, already edited it, but anyway it does not work like this

Comment: @dan-klasson Hi, no, it does work like this because the second argument pass empty with "None", any other clue of the error im getting?

Comment: @dan-klasson sorry, what do you mean?